# Statistical test for comparing Precision-Recall curves

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, precision-recall

When evaluating models' performance using Receiver Operator Characteristic (ROC) curves, [DeLong's test](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531595?seq=1) can be used to assess whether two curves are significantly different.  Is there a statistical test that can be used to determine whether two Precision-Recall curves are significantly different?